# How to find row in angular data table and hide some of the rows using condition in angular?

Tags: angular

how can i get row and hide it in angular data table

i have tried using the below code

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 bg-white rounded" >
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table table table-hover table-stripe " [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Username</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name" class="bg-info">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header >Coin</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"  [hidden]="row.name=='hydro'">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="sell">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Selling</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="bg-success">${{row.sell}}
            <span class="badge badge-info rounded">buy</span>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

i want to be able to hide some rows using some conditions

Comment: You could leverage the filter functionality. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples "Tables with Filtering" example